# Android: hierarchy viewer

Tags: android, android-layout

I succeeded in opening hierarchy viewer from tools directory. I have two emulators running but hierarchy viewer doesn't show any. Even the refresh doesn't have any difference. Can anyone help me?

Comment: [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, it seems like SDK tools v8 bug. The reason is hierarchyviewer can't find adb.exe in it's startup folder.

Don't know how to avoid this in a nice way, but as workaround I just copied hierarchyviewer.bat and whole "lib" folder from SDK \tools to \platform-tools